# vimscript: completion for vim registers

Tags: vim

I've been wondering how to make vim shortcut which would make completion popup with contents of most common/all registers. Right now this is what I've

```
fun! Reg_to_list(findstart,base)                                                                                                                                         
    let l:regs=[]                                                                                                                                                        
    let l:lvals=["+","%","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",":","*"]                                                                                                
    for a in range(0,len(l:lvals)-1)                                                                                                                                     
        let l:tmpval=substitute(getreg(l:lvals[a]),'^ *\(.*\)','\1','')                                                                                                  
        if ( l:tmpval =~ "[[:graph:]]" )                                                                                                                                 
            call add(l:regs, l:tmpval)                                                                                                                                   
        endif                                                                                                                                                            
    endfor                                                                                                                                                               
    return uniq(l:regs)                                                                                                                                                  
endfun                                                                                                                                                                   

inoremap <C-\> <C-x><C-u>
```

But I've three issues with that:

- I can't set completefunc to Reg_to_list on buffer load
- I've to remove perpending spaces so that elements will be in list
- newlines are not pasted

Comment: Note that you're passing two arguments to the function but use none of them

Comment: @Sergio It's because I wanted to map it to completefunc and it needs 2 args.